# Unable install mongo 3.6 on raspberry pi

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, armv7

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on raspberry pi 3 and i'm trying to install [Mongo 3.6](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-arm64-ubuntu1604-3.6.4.tgz) on raspberry pi followed steps as per this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) 
But i've ended up with following error

```
Cannot execute binary file : Exec Format error
```

the raspberry pi processor is ARMv7l

Comment: Is not ARMv7 32-bit? (seems to say so in the tag wiki, so probably should have read that at least ) Would you not have known that based on the Ubuntu you installed? You downloaded a 64-bit version. AFAIK 32-bit support in builds has been discontinued.

Comment: Hello. This question more likely belongs to https://serverfault.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: i couldn't install on  Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS but i was able to install on pi64 operating system [https://github.com/bamarni/pi64/releases]